# Nginx lost my static images for one site in sites-enabled

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have two sites in `sites-enabled` for `nginx`:

1) `project` - this is essentially the top level domain - mysite.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /static {
        alias  /home/www/flask-deploy/project/static/;
    }
}
```

2) `blog` - this is for a blog, that is accessible via: mysite.com:8080

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location blog/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /static {
        alias  /home/www/flask-deploy/blog/static/;
    }
}
```

Nginx has accepted both configurations, but when I visit `1` i get all of the text, but no css, or images.

If I visit `2` i get everything working fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For the `alias` directive to work correctly, the URI in the `location` and the URI in the `alias` directive should both end in `/` or neither end in `/`. The algorithm seems to substitute one string for the other.

So you should probably write:

```
location /static {
    alias  /home/www/flask-deploy/project/static;
}
```

However, when the last element(s) of the alias match the location, the `root` directive is preferred (see [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)):

```
location /static {
    root  /home/www/flask-deploy/project;
}
```

Your `location blog/` looks incorrect, prefix locations should always begin with a `/`.

Comment: how about the actual location block for 'blog' ?

Comment: should static be inside the location block for blog?

Comment: `location /blog` and `location /blog/` are acceptable for URIs that begin with `/blog` and `/blog/` respectively, the latter being a subset of the former. A nested location must be a subset or the parent URI, so `location /blog/images` could be nested within `location /blog` but `location /images` could not.