# Possible to match location directive in nginx with a port number?

Tags: nginx, flask

I have a config that looks like:
1)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /static {
        alias  /home/www/flask-deploy/project/static/;
    }
}
```

2) **updated**

```
server {
listen 8080;
server_name mysite.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
location /static/ {
    root /home/www/flask-deploy/blog;
}
```

}

**Updated issue:**

If I view `mysite.com:8080/static/css/main.css` , i can see this, but if i visit `mysite.com:8080`, it will show the content for `#1` not `#2`

Comment: See my answer to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093887/nginx-lost-my-static-images-for-one-site-in-sites-enabled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first configuration includes `alias` directive and the second consists `root`. So, that is the reason for the difference in their behaviour. Here are examples of matching URIs and real path in fs for both configurations:

**1**

```
location /static {
        alias  /home/www/flask-deploy/project/static/;
    }
```

`http://somehost:80/static/somefile` -> /home/www/flask-deploy/project/static/somefile
`http://somehost:80/static/dir/somefile` -> /home/www/flask-deploy/project/static/dir/somefile

**2**

```
location /static/ {
            root /home/www/flask-deploy/blog/static;
        }
```

`http://somehost:8080/static/somefile` -> /home/www/flask-deploy/blog/static/**static**/somefile
`http://somehost:8080/static/dir/somefile` -> /home/www/flask-deploy/blog/static/**static**/dir/somefile

Comment: So, this fixed #1, but #2 is now loading the info for static from #1. How do I get it to load the info for #2 instead? Updating my config for #2 above, if you can please help

Comment: Both `server` directives pass all requests, except `/static`, to `http://localhost:8000`. We have only the difference between the ways for serving requests with URLs, which have prefix `/static`. The #1 takes all static files from `/home/www/flask-deploy/project/static/` and the #2 takes from `/home/www/flask-deploy/blog/static/static`

Comment: Please see updated above. I removed the static from the 'root' directive. Since the files are in static/ not static/static . However, its still showing the content for #1 and not #2 any ideas?